# VsCode IntelliSense and node/web-shared classes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

as we all know, we can easily use classes from a single file for both Node and web applications.

```js
//myclass.js
class MyClass { /* ... */ };
if (typeof module === "object")
{
    module.exports = { MyClass };
}
```

However, the directive `module.exports = { MyClass };` causes IntelliSense to no more recognize `MyClass` in web js files. (Of course it's included in my *jsconfig.json*).

Adding a `/// <reference path="..." />` didn't help.

Adding a `@typedef ... @type {import(...)` JsDoc didn't help.

I won't blame VsCode for having a bug here but I rather think I've got something wrong.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.